# Scala - how come using a super-type with two generic parameters cause the scala type checker to treat the child-type differently?

Tags: scala, generics, subclass, contravariance

I ran into an interesting situation. I wanted to implement something that looked like the following.

```
object Test {
  abstract class Key[A]
  class Constraint[-A] {
    def doSomething(a: A): String = ""
  }

  object DesiredKeyConstraints {
    case class KeyConstraint[A](val key: Key[A], constraint: Constraint[A])
    val data: Map[Key[_], KeyConstraint[_]] = Map()
  }

  def useTheKeyConstraints[A](key: Key[A], value: A): String = {
    DesiredKeyConstraints.data.get(key).fold[String]("") {
      case DesiredKeyConstraints.KeyConstraint(_, constraint) =>  constraint.doSomething(value)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("hi")
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I pull a KeyConstraint out of the map, I no longer know its type. So, when I try to call `doSomething`, the types don't check out. This all seems to behave as expected. What was interesting is that elsewhere in the codebase, we have something that looks like the following: (replacing `DesiredKeyConstraints` with `WorkingKeyConstraints`)

```
object Test {
  abstract class Key[A]
  class Constraint[-A] {
    def doSomething(a: A): String = ""
  }

  object WorkingKeyConstraints {
    sealed trait SuperTrait[A, B] {
      val key: Key[A]
    }
    case class KeyConstraint[A](val key: Key[A], constraint: Constraint[A]) extends SuperTrait[A, Unit]
    val data: Map[Key[_], SuperTrait[_, _]] = Map()
  }

  def useTheKeyConstraints[A](key: Key[A], value: A): String = {
    WorkingKeyConstraints.data.get(key).fold[String]("") {
      case WorkingKeyConstraints.KeyConstraint(_, constraint) =>  constraint.doSomething(value)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("hi")
  }
}
```

This one compiles and runs just fine. For some reason, having the super-type means that when we extract the KeyConstraint from the Map, it treats it as a `KeyConstraint[Any]` rather than a `KeyConstraint[_]`. Because `Constraint`'s are contravariant, we can treat a `Constraint[Any]` as a `Constraint[A]` and so the code compiles. The key problem/question here is, why does having the super type cause the type-checker to treat it as a `KeyConstraint[Any]`?

Also, as further information, I played around with this some more, and it is something specific to having a super-type that has two generic type parameters. If I do the child-class with two generic types or a parent with a single generic type, it still fails. See my other failed attempts below:

```
object AnotherCaseThatDoesntWorkKeyConstraints {
  case class KeyConstraint[A, B](val key: Key[A], constraint: Constraint[A])
  val data: Map[Key[_], KeyConstraint[_, _]] = Map()
}

object AThirdCaseThatDoesntWorkKeyConstraints {
  sealed trait SuperTrait[A] {
    val key: Key[A]
  }
  case class KeyConstraint[A](val key: Key[A], constraint: Constraint[A]) extends SuperTrait[A]
  val data: Map[Key[_], SuperTrait[_]] = Map()
}
```

I assume this is some sort of bug in the Scala type checker, but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: How does it fail? Which line and with what error? Currently, all your examples compile for me.

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco, not the first one, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Type erasure and pattern matching

Typing the `Map` with `SuperTrait` concealed information about the type, and caused the pattern matching to assume a broad type for your extractor.

---

This is a similar example, but using `Any` instead of your `SuperTrait`. This example also shows how to produce a runtime exception out of it.

```
case class Identity[A : Manifest]() {
  def apply(a: A) = a match { case a: A => a } // seemingly safe no-op
}

val myIdentity: Any = Identity[Int]()

myIdentity match {
  case f@Identity() => f("string") // uh-oh, passed String instead of Int
}
```

throws an exception

```
scala.MatchError: string (of class java.lang.String)
  at Identity.apply(...)
```

`f@Identity()` pattern matches the `Any` as an `Identity[Any]`, and due to type erasure, this matched the `Identity[Int]`, which turned into the error.

---

In constrast if we change `Any` to `Identity[_]`,

```
case class Identity[A : Manifest]() {
  def apply(a: A) = a match { case a: A => a }
}

val myIdentity: Identity[_] = Identity[Int]()

myIdentity match {
  case f@Identity() => f("string")
}
```

correctly fails to compile.

```
found   : String("string")
required: _$1 where type _$1
     case f@Identity() => f("string")
```

It knows that `f` is the existential type `Identity[T] forSome {type T}`, and it can't show that `String` conforms to the wildcard type `T`.

---

In the first example, you were effectively pattern matching as

```
DesiredKeyConstraints.KeyConstraint[Any](_, constraint)
```

In the second, there was more information, and you were matching as

```
DesiredKeyConstraints.KeyConstraint[T](_, constraint) forSome {type T}
```

(This is just illustrative; you currently can't actually write type parameters when pattern matching.)

Comment: Any idea why using `SuperTrait[A, B]` hides the type, but using `SuperTrait[A]` doesn't?

Comment: @RichardShurtz, it's because `KeyConstraint[A] extends SuperTrait[A]` implies `KeyConstraint[T] <: SuperTrait[T]` for any type `T`. But `KeyConstraint[A] extends SuperTrait[A, Unit]` does not imply `KeyConstraint[T] <: SuperTrait[T, S]` for any types `T` and `S`. The relationship is lost. Change your type annotation from `SuperTrait[_, _]` to `SuperTrait[_, Unit]`, and I suspect it will have a different result.

Comment: Ahh... yep, this explains it